# Circles not appearing on Canvas

Tags: processing, mouseevent

I'm trying to build a connect4 game with processing, following a tutorial.

[What I have so far is here.](https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/1018757)

[The tutorial is here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbKJqeOxQQ4)

I stopped at the 4:05 mark to check my code but I noticed something...I don't know why but circles *should* pop up when I click but they aren't....can someone help pls? Thanks.

Just in case, here's the code:

```
int h = 6; 
int w = 7;
int bs = 100;
int[][] board = new int[h][w];
int player = 1;

void setup() {
    size(700, 600);
    ellipseMode(CORNER);

}

int nextSpace(int x){
    for (int y = h - 1; y >= 0; y--) if (board[y][x] == 0) return y;
    return -1;
}

void mousePressed(){
    int x = mouseX / bs; 
    int y = nextSpace(x);
    if (y >= 0){
        board[y][x] = player;
        player = player == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    }

}

void draw() {
    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++){
            fill(255);
            rect(i * bs, j * bs, bs, bs);
            if (board[j][i] > 0){
                fill(board[j][i] == 1 ? 255 : 0, board[j][i] == 2 ? 255 : 0, 0);
                ellipse(i * bs, j * bs, bs, bs);
            
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: A link to an off-site resource is not sufficient you have to add the relevant code to the question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time you have this kind of issue try to use a systematic approach to define where is your bug:

- Is your `draw()` function broken? To check that put something in your board and see if it shows. For example add `board[1][1]=1` in your `setup()` and you'll see a circle appearing so the issue is not in `draw()`
- So if you click on the screen does it update your `board` as expected? The first thing is to add a simple `println("Clicked");` in `mousePressed()`. Now you see that your click event is working well since the string is shown each time you click, so it must be an issue with how you get your `x` and `y`.
- Use `println(x);` and `println(y)`; in `mousePressed()` to have an idea of your values. You will notice that you don't get integers for `x` you get decimal number.

And this is your issue: you can not access `board[1.543]` it doesn't make sense, so you need to keep only the integer part of `mouseX / bs`. To do that you can use [`int()`](https://processing.org/reference/intconvert_.html) like this:

```
int x = int(mouseX / bs);
```

And your sketch is now working fine.